# QWebEngineView cookie

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно перед переходом на страницу добавить свои cookie, возможно ли это сделать в QWebEngineView или QWebEnginePage? не знаю даже в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Вот здесь, например, этот вопрос обсуждается http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_10846_0.html

Comment: там рассматривается случай с QWebView, я же использую QWebEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `QWebEngineProfile` имеется возможность получить путь к постоянному (persistent) хранилищу данных (файл БД SQLite), содержащему в том числе и куки. Можете просто ради эксперимента взять любой проект с `QtWebEngine` и прописать для `QWebEnginePage` путь в какую-нибудь папку:

```
my_web_view->page()->profile()
    ->setPersistentStoragePath(QCoreApplication
        ::applicationDirPath() + QLatin1String("/storage"));
```

Теперь в папке `storage` приложения появится файл, который можно править, как собственноручно с помощью многочисленных вьюверов БД SQLite, так и программно, используя модуль `SQL` самого Qt.

Comment: `ui->widget->page()->profile()->setPersistentStoragePath("C:/cookies"); `устанавливаю перед `load(QUrl &)` на диске вижу файлы базы данных, и там в таблице даже есть мои куки, но вот при повторном запуске программы они "не подхватываются", то есть `alert($.cookie('alwaysMenu'));` выдает null

Comment: Добавил при добавление cookies параметр { expires: 9999 } и теперь все нормально загружается после перезапуска программы.

Answer (score 0):

[QNetworkCookie](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qnetworkcookie.html) доступен для QtWebEngine, но только через старый `QNetworkAccessManager`, поскольку `QtWebEngine` использует собственную реализацию протокола HTTP. При рассмотрении [одного из этих примеров](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-browser-browser-pro.html) обратите внимание на это:

```
contains(DEFINES, QWEBENGINEPAGE_SETNETWORKACCESSMANAGER) {
    HEADERS += cookiejar.h networkaccessmanager.h
    SOURCES += cookiejar.cpp networkaccessmanager.cpp
}
```

Более подробные примеры доступны по ссылке [WebEngine Tab Browser Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-browser-example.html).

PS. Это мой перевод с английского [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675026/qt-5-access-cookies-in-qtwebengine/27675237#27675237).